# Check empty lines in Python

Tags: python, regex, text

I have a text file which contains multiple number of lines. I want to check a specific line *(calling xyz ...)* in present or not in between two line(++ start line and -- exiting line). If the line *(calling xyz ...)* is present then it should return the line and if line is not present then NULL value should be return. I want to store the result in to a list.

Example file:

```
++ start line 
22 15:36:53 
dog, cat, monkey, rat
calling xxxxx
animal already added
-- exiting line
```

Above block of line should add **calling xxxxx** to list.

```
++ start line 
12 12:56:34 
cat, camel, cow, dog    
animal already added
-- exiting line
```

In above block calling xyz is missing so it should add NULL to the list

Expected Output

```
calling xxxxx
NULL
```

Comment: You will get a much more friendly reception and much better help here if you show what code you have tried so far and describe what problems you were having with it. Without code, your question looks like a request for free consulting and many people don't like that.

Comment: I don't have any idea about the code because I can't think of the logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex to check the condition that you have mentioned:

```
^\+\+(?=(?:(?!\-\-).)*\s+(calling[^\n]+)).*?\s+--
```

[Observe how the regex works here](https://regex101.com/r/JMCoPQ/7)

If it matches then you get the calling line as group 1

Sample Source ( [run here](https://ideone.com/DZw13J) ):

```
import re

regex = r"(?:^\+\+(?=(?:(?!\-\-).)*\s+(calling[^\n]+)).*?\s+--)|(?:^\+\+(?=(?:(?!\-\-).)*\s+(?!calling[^\n]+)).*?\s+--)"

test_str = ("++ start line \n"
    "22 15:36:53 \n"
    "dog, cat, monkey, rat\n"
    "calling xxxxx\n"
    "animal already added\n"
    "-- exiting line\n\n\n"
    "++ start line \n"
    "12 12:56:34 \n"
    "cat, camel, cow, dog    \n"
    "animal already added\n"
    "-- exiting line\n\n"
    "++ start line \n"
    "12 12:56:34 \n"
    "cat, camel, cow, dog  \n"
    "calling pqr  \n"
    "animal already added\n"
    "-- exiting line\n\n")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)

for match in matches:
    print(match.group(1))
```

Output:

```
calling xxxxx
None
calling pqr
```

Comment: @Satish if that worked for you then you can accept this as answer.  As you seem new here thus sharing how it is done:  [How to Accept Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Sorry for that @Rizwan M.Tuman, I was stucked in another problem so I missed it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use **multiple** patterns, one for separating the block, one for search `calling...` in the block.

1. Expression for the block (see [**a demo here**](https://regex101.com/r/DBshIw/1/)):

   `^\+\+
   (?P<block>[\s\S]+?)
   ^--.+`
2. Expression for `calling...`:

   `^calling.+`

---

As a `Python` snippet:

```
import re
rx_block = re.compile(r'''
    ^\+\+
    (?P<block>[\s\S]+?)
    ^--.+''', re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE)

rx_calling = re.compile(r'''
    ^calling.+
    ''', re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE)

numbers = [number.group(0) if number else None
            for block in rx_block.finditer(your_string_here)
            for number in [rx_calling.search(block.group('block'))]]
print(numbers)
```

Which yields

```
['calling xxxxx', None]
```

Comment: I am getting unexpected output as:  [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'calling xxxx', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'calling xyz', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None

Comment: @Satish: And exactly **what** would you expect?

Comment: Thank you for your help @Jan. Here I have got so many null value but actually there are some line starting with calling. So I should get less null value.

Answer (score 0):

One can use split function to get sub-parts and check them:

```
outlist = []
with open("calling.txt", "r") as ff:
    lines = ff.read()
    records = lines.split("++ start line ")
    records = list(filter(lambda x: len(x)>0, records))
    for rec in records:
        found = False
        rows = rec.split("\n")
        for row in rows:
            if not found and row.startswith("calling"):
                outlist.append(row.split(" ")[1])
                found = True
        if not found: 
            outlist.append("NULL")

print(outlist)
```

Output:

```
['xxxxx', 'NULL', 'pqr']
```

Comment: What I got is unexpected: ['sequencer', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'charge_on.bat', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'sequencer', 'NULL'

Comment: I presume you are on Windows (I am working on LInux). Instead of `rec.split("\n")` use `rec.split("\r\n")` or try `rec.split(os.linesep)` (you have to mention `import os` for second option).

Comment: Sorry but I got the same output.